# How to reduce image size without pixelation?

Tags: opengl, android, textures, assets, scale

I see lots of games with smooth edges characters and high res images, however when I try to reduce images to say 64x64 for my character I just get a pixelated mess. even if I start with a 64x64 canvas I get pixelated edges.

Should I be scaling with OpenGL? or is there some technique perhaps with photoshop or pixen that I am unaware of?

Comment: can you provide an visual example ?

Comment: Related: [Scaling down pixel art](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45469/how-do-i-scale-down-pixel-art) and [vector art](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/rendering-scaled-down-card-images).

Comment: From your description, it would seem that the scaling algorithm you're using does nearest-pixel interpolation rather than the smoother Lanczos interpolation. Is [that question about scaling down vector art](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/rendering-scaled-down-card-images) helpful?

Comment: Yes that vector scaling answer is useful. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sounds like the scaling algorithm you're using isn't interpolating pixels.

Pictures are best explained with pictures:

[image: scaling an image with different interpolations]

It's [the Major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motoko_Kusanagi), first in full, then scaled down with [Lanczos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) (left) and nearest-pixel (a.k.a. no interpolation) (right) to two sizes.

The same comparison, in 3x magnified:

[image: detail view]

Make sure the scaling you're using is resampling sensibly. For example, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) has a `-filter Lanczos` option.

It doesn't even need to be fancy Lanczos, in case your tools can't do it; cubic (leftmost) looks the same to me:

[image: cubic on the left]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and show examples images. Much appreciated.